# Generate distinct XML elements with XSLT and Ant

Tags: xslt, ant

I am trying to get set of unique elements `command` in terms of attribute `@name`. When I use the XSLT IDE `Exchange XML editor` it works. But with `ant` `xslt-task` it doesn't work. Here is the XSLT:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
    <xsl:key name="commandUnique" match="command" use="@name"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="//command[generate-id() = generate-id(key('commandUnique', @name)[1])]">
            <xsl:element name="{@name}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the input XML file:

```
 <commands>
    <command name="get-version"/>
    <command name="answer-get-version"/>
    <command name="get-version"/>
    <command name="read-m-tods"/>
    <command name="read-m-tods"/>
    <command name="answer-read-m-tods"/>
    <command name="answer-read-m-tods"/>
    <command name="get-slave-request"/>
    <command name="answer-get-slave-request"/>
    <command name="answer-read-m-tods"/>
    <command name="write-m-tods"/>
    <command name="answer-write-m-tods"/>
 </commands>
```

The output indeed is this:

```
<root/>
```

The expected output is this:

```
<root>
   <get-version/>
   <answer-get-version/>
   <read-m-tods/>
   <answer-read-m-tods/>
   <get-slave-request/>
   <answer-get-slave-request/>
   <write-m-tods/>
   <answer-write-m-tods/>
</root>
```

In the output we have set of all unique pairs `command/@name` (without repetition).

It is interesting that when I do the transformation using the XSLT IDE I get exactly what I want, but when I use `ant` I get only `<root/>`.

Here this is the `ant` task:

```
<target name="get-unique-objects">
    <basename property="tod-file-base-name" file="${file}"/>
    <xslt in="${input-file}" out="${output-file-dir}/${tod-file-base-name}-unique-objects.xml" extension=".xml" style="xslt/projects/asp-bus/implementation/xsl/stylesheet-get-unique-properties.xsl">
        <classpath location="../../../../infrastructure/SaxonEE9-7-0-11J/saxon9ee.jar:/net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
    </xslt>
</target>
```

The `ant` and the IDE are using different(in terms of version/release) processors. BUT both processors are Saxon and both support `XSLT 2` but it somehow works with the one, and doesn't with the other. I tried something simple, just to make sure that the `ant task`  is OK and it worked as well. I suspect the problem has something to do with the `generate-id(key(...))` stuff. No warning and errors during the transformation. I get only empty element `<root/>` at the output (when ran via ant).

Comment: For testing, change the code to do `<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>` in addition to the `xsl:for-each`, then we can at least see whether the Ant task processes the right contents. I suspect somehow the input to the Ant task is different, either the wrong file or some namespaces that cause the `for-each` to select nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The following `<classpath>` looks unusual:

```
<classpath
    location="../../../../infrastructure/SaxonEE9-7-0-11J/saxon9ee.jar:/net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
```

Notice the slash (`/`) at the beginning of `/net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl`. I believe this will cause Ant to look for a file literally named `net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl` under the root directory.

Try replacing the `<xslt>` task with the following:

```
<xslt in="${input-file}" out="${output-file-dir}/${tod-file-base-name}-unique-objects.xml" style="xslt/projects/asp-bus/implementation/xsl/stylesheet-get-unique-properties.xsl">
    <classpath location="../../../../infrastructure/SaxonEE9-7-0-11J/saxon9ee.jar"/>
    <factory name="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
</xslt>
```

The above example:

- Changes the `<classpath>` so it points to just the Saxon JAR file.
- Adds a `<factory>` element.